# Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

In this application, I am trying to create a quiz application.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';

const axios = require('axios').default;

const PlayQuiz = () => {
    // declaring all the state here
    const [questionsArray, setQuestionsArray] = useState([]);


    // Using effects here
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: 'get', 
            url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10',
        }).then(res => {console.log(Object.values(res.data)[1]); setQuestionsArray(Object.values(res.data)[1])})
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {console.log(questionsArray)}, [questionsArray]);

    // Returning html markup here 
    return (<>
        <div className = 'questions-container'>
            {/* {questionsArray.map(questionObject => <h1>{questionObject.question}</h1>)} */}
    <h1>{questionsArray[0].question}</h1>
        </div>
    </>)
}


export default PlayQuiz;
```

(btw all the console logs that this code contains is just for me to visualise of what exactly is going on)

In the following code, I use `axios`to fetch data from the API and then resolve the data in my `questionsArray`. Then I want to print a heading tag into my dom which contains the first element inside my array, i.e. the object and get that object's question property which contains the actual question. But when I do this: `<h1>{questionsArray[0].questions}</h1>`, it throws an error, saying cannot read property questions of undefined.

Just in case, if anyone of you want to see the object that I get from the API:
[image]

And from this object, I get the results object value from the data key in the object, and set it to `questionsArray`.

If anyone of you wants to see what gets stored inside my `questionsArray`:
[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try optional chaining `?.`

```
<h1>{questionsArray[0]?.question}</h1>
```

Check this out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lovelace-06u3x?file=/src/App.js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: By doing this, it doesn't throw that error, but it doesn't print that heading containing that question. How do I print that question out in the DOM as a heading?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lovelace-06u3x?file=/src/App.js
After some wait, when the data fetched, then it will print that question.

Comment: This link just redirects me to codesandbox default code, that gets executed the first time you open codesandbox. This doesn't contain any code

Comment: can you please retry again ? I have also added the link my answer as well.

Comment: yeah sure, I am opening that link again

Comment: Yeah that worked, but can you please explain what 
questionsArray[0]?.question mean?

Comment: questionsArray[0]?.question  means 

if `questionsArray[0]` exists then only search for `question` key within `questionsArray[0]` i.e. `questionsArray[0].question`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222172/discussion-between-maybenextt1me-and-keshav).

Answer (score 0):

When React is rendering your data, axios is not completely fetced your data and your questionsArray is either undefined or empty. Just check if axios is finished fetching data.

```js
return (<>
    <div className = 'questions-container'>
        {/* {questionsArray && questionsArray.map(questionObject => <h1>{questionObject.question}</h1>)} */}
<h1>{questionsArray[0].question}</h1>
    </div>
</>)
```

This will ensure your data is defined or not empty

Comment: How do I check if axios is finished fetching my data?

Comment: Look at the answer. I used questionsArray && questionsArray.map(......)

Comment: Also, when I use the above map component which has been commented, it works just fine. If axios is still fetching from the API then why is that commented line not giving me any error?

Comment: Just uncomment that line then or just use chaining <h1>{questionsArray[0]?.question}</h1>

Comment: So you are saying me to uncomment ` {/* {questionsArray && questionsArray.map(questionObject => <h1>{questionObject.question}</h1>)} */}` this and execute it?

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. It prints every question that object contain, but the line below it `<h1>{questionArray[0].question}</h1>` doesn't get executed.

Comment: If You want to print just one first line try something like this <h1>{questionArray[0].question ? questionArray[0].question : ""}</h1>

Comment: Nope. It again throws the error that I was getting before

Comment: Can you do an if check before rendering. Something like this